# directory tree warning

Tags: perl

i have writed some script, that recursively print's directory's content. But it prints warning for each folder. How to fix this?

sample folder:

> dev# cd /tmp/test
> dev# ls -p -R
> test2/
> testfile
> testfile2
>
> ./test2:
> testfile3
> testfile4

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

browseDir('/tmp/test');

sub browseDir {
    my $path = shift;
    opendir(my $dir, $path);
    while (readdir($dir)) {
        next if /^\.{1,2}$/;
        if (-d "$path/$_") {
            browseDir("$path/$_");
        }
        print "$path/$_\n";
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

and the output:

> dev# perl /tmp/cotest.pl
> /tmp/test/test2/testfile3
>   /tmp/test/test2/testfile4
> Use of uninitialized value $_ in
>   concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/cotest.pl line 16.
> /tmp/test/
>   /tmp/test/testfile
> /tmp/test/testfile2

Comment: `File::Spec` <- this module have `no_upwards()` func to hide all directories like `.` or `..`. Example: `@paths = File::Spec->no_upwards( @paths );`

Comment: You should put a `use 5.012;` in your program since you use `while(readdir($dir)){...}` which doesn't work in earlier releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you try that code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    browseDir('/tmp');

    sub browseDir {
        my $path = shift;
        opendir(my $dir, $path);
        while (readdir($dir)) {
            next if /^\.{1,2}$/;
            print "$path/$_\n";
            if (-d "$path/$_") {
                browseDir("$path/$_");
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
```

If you got that error, its because you call browseDir() before use variable $_.

Comment: thanks, it works. also if i don't use $_ variable no warnings prints. `while (my $s = readdir($dir)) {...}`

Comment: Did the OP change his code? I can't find any difference between yours and his.

Comment: `print "$path/$_\n";` moved up

Comment: @Suic it works with another variable. But the point is, $_ is reset after function call.

Comment: The problem is that the loop `while (readdir($dir)) {...}` terminates only when `$_` is undefined. Because `$_` is a global variable, calling `browseDir` before printing its value will try to print `undef`. You can fix this by using a lexical variable for the loop, or by using `local $_` at the top oif the subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You place a value in `$_` before calling `browseDir` and you expect it the value to be present after calling `browseDir` (a reasonable expectation), but `browseDir` modifies that variable.

Just add `local $_;` to `browseDir` to make sure that any change to it are undone before the sub exits.

---

Unrelated to your question, here are three other issues:

- Not even minimal error checking!
- You could run out of directory handles will navigating a deep directory.
- You filter out files `".\n"` and `"..\n"`.

Fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

browseDir('/tmp/test');

sub browseDir {
    my $path = shift;

    opendir(my $dh, $path) or die $!;
    my @files = readdir($dh);
    closedir($dh);

    for (@files) {
        next if /^\.{1,2}z/;
        if (-d "$path/$_") {
            browseDir("$path/$_");
        }

        print "$path/$_\n";
    }
}
```

---

Finally, why don't use you a module like [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule)?

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
print "$_\n" for File::Find::Rule->in('/tmp');
```

---

Note: Before 5.12, `while (readir($dh))` would have to be written `while (defined($_ = readdir($dh)))`

Comment: Actually `while(readdir($dir)){...}` gets converted to `while(defined($_ = readdir($dir))){...}` as of [5.12](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#readdir-DIRHANDLE). [commit](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/114c60ecb1f775ef1deb4fdc8fb8e3a6f343d13d) Unfortunately this never made it into a delta.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, oh really! Then the problem is lack of localisation of `$_`. The recursive call is clobbering the value the parent holds in `$_`. Updated answer.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that bit of code could be modified to use `local $_`. It probably never came up since it is usually only used for `readline`. The only backwards compatibly problem is that `$_` would then get reset after the loop.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I meant "the OP's problem is lack of localisation of `$_`". I wasn't suggesting `while readline` should do that.

Comment: Added File::Find::Rule solution to the post since it's only two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module? It's included in almost all distributions of Perl since Perl 5.x. It's not my favorite module due to the sort of messy way it works, but it does a good job.

You define a `wanted` subroutine that does what you want and filter out what you don't want. In this case, you're printing pretty much everything, so all `wanted` does is print out what is found.

In `File::Find`, the name of the file is kept in `$File::Find::name` and the directory for that file is in `$File::Find::dir`. The `$_` is the file itself, and can be used for testing.

Here's a basic way of what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;

my $directory = `/tmp/test`;

find ( \&wanted, $directory );

sub wanted {
    say $File::Find::Name;
}
```

I prefer to put my `wanted` function in my `find` subroutine, so they're together. This is equivalent to the above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;

my $directory = `/tmp/test`;

find ( 
    sub { 
        say $File::Find::Name
    },
    $directory,
);
```

Good programming says not to print in subroutines. Instead, you should use the subroutine to store and return your data. Unfortunately, `find` doesn't return anything at all. You have to use a *global* array to capture the list of files, and later print them out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;

my $directory = `/tmp/test`;
my @directory_list;

find ( 
    sub { 
        push @directory_list, $File::Find::Name
    }, $directory );

for my $file (@directory_list) {
   say $file;
}
```

Or, if you prefer a separate `wanted` subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;

my $directory = `/tmp/test`;
my @directory_list;

find ( \&wanted, $directory );
sub wanted {
    push @directory_list, $File::Find::Name;
}

for my $file (@directory_list) {
   say $file;
}
```

The fact that my wanted subroutine depends upon an array that's not local to the subroutine bothers me which is why I prefer embedding the `wanted` subroutine inside my `find` call.

One thing you can do is use your subroutine to filter out what you want. Let's say you're only interested in JPG files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Find;

my $directory = `/tmp/test`;
my @directory_list;

find ( \&wanted, $directory );
sub wanted {
    next unless /\.jpg$/i;  #Skip everything that doesn't have .jpg suffix
    push @directory_list, $File::Find::Name;
}

for my $file (@directory_list) {
   say $file;
}
```

Note how the wanted subroutine does a `next` on any file I don't want before I push it into my `@directory_list` array. Again, I prefer the embedding:

```
find (sub {
    next unless /\.jpg$/i;  #Skip everything that doesn't have .jpg suffix
    push @directory_list, $File::Find::Name;
}
```

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but I just wanted to let you know about the `Find::File` module and introduce you to Perl modules (if you didn't already know about them) which can add a lot of functionality to Perl.